# pt-table-checksum says there is a difference but pt-table-sync with --print says nothing

Tags: mysql, pt-table-checksum

I am using pt-table-checksum to ensure master-slave is synchronized.

When I run pt-table-checksum, I see some differences on employee_profile.trigger_log but when I use pt-table-sync with --print, I see nothing.

I resolved some differences on some tables with pt-table-sync but when I re-test with pt-table-checksum, this tool still says there is a difference.

So what is the problem with pt-table-checksum ? Is is accuracy ?

[UPDATE]

I use

```
pt-table-checksum -h <masterip> -u <the_user> -p '<passwd of the user>' --recursion-method dsn=h=<slaveip>,P=3306,u=<the_userr>,p=<passwd of the user>,D=check_db,t=dsns --nocheck-binlog-format --set-vars innodb_lock_wait_timeout=50 > ~/stats_check_db_<slaveip>.txt
```

After that, I run command to filter:

```
cat ~/stats_check_db_<slaveip>.txt | awk '{print "*"$3"*" " -- " $8}' | grep -Fv  "*0*"
```

This is output:

```
*DIFFS* -- TABLE
*1* -- mysql.user
*1* -- employee_profile.entry
*1* -- employee_profile.ip
*1* -- employee_profile.thread
```

When I run pt-table-sync:

```
pt-table-sync  --print h=<slaveip>,P=3306,u=<the user>,p=<passwd of the user> --sync-to-master --databases employee_profile --tables entry
```

I see nothing. After a while, when I re-check with pt-table-checksum, I don't see difference on employee_profile.entry

For a resolved table, I still see some differences on next re-check. These are disappeared from result of pt-table-checksum on the third checksum.

[UPDATE 2]

I am using percona toolkit version 2.2.13 - lastest version on http://www.percona.com/

I reviewed all implementations of db server that I did checksum. These are old implementation of mysql or mariadb that someone built them.

I see the problem just appear when the implementation between master and slave is different such as master is MariaDB 5.5.34 and slave is MariaDB 5.5.37 (I see false positive error: Cannot nibble table because MySQL chose no index instead of the PRIMARY index - just ignore it and then execute pt-table-sync) or master is mysql 5.5.35 and slave is mysql 5.5.37 (I see pt-table-checksum says there is a difference but pt-table-sync --print says nothing - just re-test for sure).

I think it is a reason for false positive errors.

Thank you so much !

Comment: Is it on a float or double? I got sometime some false positives on that due to different formats. Otherwise, please provide the full output in order to search the specific row where the difference is (use `--replicate-check-only`, lower chunk size).

Comment: I saw that too. Different MySQL versions may produce different output which will trigger mismatches.

Answer (score 1):

There were false positives in old versions of pt-table-checksum. Make sure you don't run ancient version.

To check what the differences are you could also use this script():

```
#./compare_table.sh <db> <table> <master> <slave>



#!/bin/bash

# Usage:
# $0 database table master slave
set -eux
db=$1
tbl=$2
master=$3
slave=$4
tmpdir=`mktemp -d`

checksum_table="percona.checksums"

chunks=`mysql -h $slave -NBe "select chunk from $checksum_table where (this_crc<>master_crc or this_cnt<>master_cnt) AND db='$db' AND tbl='$tbl'"`

for c in $chunks
do
    echo "# $db.$tbl, chunk $c"
    chunk_index=`mysql -h $slave -NBe "SELECT chunk_index FROM $checksum_table WHERE db='$db' AND tbl='$tbl' AND chunk = '$c'"`
    index_fields=`mysql -h $slave -NBe "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.STATISTICS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='$db' AND TABLE_NAME='$tbl' AND INDEX_NAME='$chunk_index' ORDER BY SEQ_IN_INDEX"`
    index_field_last=`mysql -h $slave -NBe "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.STATISTICS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='$db' AND TABLE_NAME='$tbl' AND INDEX_NAME='$chunk_index' ORDER BY SEQ_IN_INDEX DESC LIMIT 1"`
# EXAMPLE:
#
#WHERE 
#    (
#    (`user_id` > ?) 
#    OR 
#    (`user_id` = ? AND `activity_id` > ?) 
#    OR 
#    (`user_id` = ? AND `activity_id` = ? AND `activity_type_id` >= ?)
#    ) 
#AND 
#  (
#    (`user_id` < ?) 
#    OR 
#    (`user_id` < ?) 
#    OR 
#    (`user_id` = ? AND `activity_id` < ?) 
#    OR 
#    (`user_id` = ? AND `activity_id` = ? AND `activity_type_id` <= ?)
#    )
    if [ "$chunk_index" != "NULL" ]
    then
        where="WHERE"
        v_num=1
        lower_boundary=`mysql -h $slave -NBe "SELECT lower_boundary FROM $checksum_table WHERE db='$db' AND tbl='$tbl' AND chunk = '$c'"`
        upper_boundary=`mysql -h $slave -NBe "SELECT upper_boundary FROM $checksum_table WHERE db='$db' AND tbl='$tbl' AND chunk = '$c'"`
        clause_fields=""
        where="$where (0 "
        for f in $index_fields
        do 
            clause_fields="$f $clause_fields"
            op=""
            where="$where OR ( 1"
            for cf in $clause_fields
            do
                if test -z "$op"
                then   
                    if [ $cf == $index_field_last ]
                    then   
                        op=">="
                    else   
                        op=">"
                    fi
                else   
                    op="="
                fi
                v=`echo $lower_boundary | awk -F, "{ print \\\$$v_num}"`
                v_num=$(( $v_num + 1))
                where="$where AND \`$cf\` $op '$v'"
            done
            where="$where )"
        done
        where="$where )"

        v_num=1
        clause_fields=""
        where="$where AND ( 0"
        for f in $index_fields
        do 
            clause_fields="$f $clause_fields"
            op=""
            where="$where OR ( 1"
            for cf in $clause_fields
            do
                if test -z "$op"
                then   
                    if [ $cf == $index_field_last ]
                    then   
                        op="<="
                    else   
                        op="<"
                    fi
                else   
                    op="="
                fi
                v=`echo $upper_boundary | awk -F, "{ print \\\$$v_num}"`
                v_num=$(( $v_num + 1))
                where="$where AND \`$cf\` $op '$v'"
            done
            where="$where )"
        done
        where="$where )"
    else
        where="WHERE  1 "
    fi
    echo $where
    mysql -h $master -NBe "SELECT * FROM $db.$tbl $where"  >> "$tmpdir/master"
    mysql -h $slave -NBe "SELECT * FROM $db.$tbl $where"  >> "$tmpdir/slave"
    set +e
    diff -u "$tmpdir/master" "$tmpdir/slave" | less -S
    set -e
done
rm -r "$tmpdir"
```

Comment: I am using percona toolkit version 2.2.13. I reviewed all implementations of db server that I did checksum. I see the problem about just appear when the implementation between master and slave is different such as master is MariaDB 5.5.34 and slave is MariaDB 5.5.37 (I see false positive error: Cannot nibble table because MySQL chose no index instead of the PRIMARY index) or master is mysql 5.5.35 and slave is mysql 5.5.37 (I see pt-table-checksum says there is a difference but pt-table-sync --print says nothing). Thank you !